# MPIRUN - symbol lookup error - undefined symbol

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have Fortran code that is compiled using mpiifort. I have an error when running this code using mpirun. Bellow I am pasting both how I compile and run. I get two warnings that are ignored, and one error. I believe the error is the real issue, not the warnings. I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
mpiifort mycode.f90  -r8 -O2 -xHost -override-limits -o output.out

[me@gauss ORIGINALV]$  mpirun -n 1 ./output.out
[gauss:31148] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/local/openmpi/1.10.0/lib/openmpi/mca_plm_tm: libtorque.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
[gauss:31148] mca: base: component_find: unable to open /usr/local/openmpi/1.10.0/lib/openmpi/mca_ras_tm: libtorque.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (ignored)
./output.out: symbol lookup error: /srv/home/shaorshadze/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.150/linux/mpi/intel64/lib/libmpifort.so.12: undefined symbol: MPI_UNWEIGHTED

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:
```

Comment: Did you install mpi / intel suite on the system?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Use [tag:fortran] to tag your Fortran questions. Add a specific version when necessary to distinguish (not here).

Comment: Are you able to compile and run any other program? How did you install MPI? If it is a large system and you are just a user, how did you set-up your environment?

Comment: A typical MPI implementation mix-up case. Check your `PATH` and make sure that the path to Intel MPI (used to compile the executable) comes **before** the path to Open MPI. The same applies to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Both implementations do not play nicely with one another.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was in fact the issue with the path to Intel MPI.